# Repeated measures with nested data in R

Tags: r, mixed-model, multilevel-analysis, nested-data

Previously, I conducted a model like the following. I have repeated measures (**Time** factor: pre-post) of depressive mood in two different groups (**Group** factor: neutral and experimental). Each participant in only one group. I checked the Coping as a moderator.

```
lmer(DepressiveMood ~ Coping*Time*Group + (1|ID), data = data)
```

Currently, I created 3 **Level**s among the participants based on their pre-depressive mood scores as a low, average, and high depressive mood. So, the difference can be more sizeable. However, I could not create the model. Is this following model correct? My question is individuals in three different levels of depressive mood (Level factor) are different?

```
lmer(DepressiveMood ~ Coping*Time*Group + (1|Level|ID), data = data)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using lme4 (do you?) and you wanted to have a random effect for the interactions of `Level` and `ID`, you would use:

`lmer(DepressiveMood ~ Coping*Time*Group + (1|Level:ID), data = data)`

(note the colon `:` instead of the bar `|`).

If you want an extra random effect both for `Level` and `ID`, separately, use:

`lmer(DepressiveMood ~ Coping*Time*Group + (1|Level) + (1|ID), data = data)`